# How to prevent/disable Unity's Launcher from launching when dragging (& dropping) a file?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, ccsm

When I drag a file in Nautilus to drop it somewhere else (in a different folder but still within the same Nautilus window), **Launcher launches** with some "active" icons (the rest of 'em "disabled" / "grayed-out" for the time of that "revelation"). Which icons are "active" depends on the type of file being dragged, but Nautilus and the Rubbish Bin will always (?) be active.

I've noticed this happens in particular when **horizontal scroll** is visible in Nautilus (e.g., when you have long file names, etc) and when the file you drag is the one **from the bottom of the list**.

I've never found this "feature" useful, and would like to disable it. A quick check in **CCSM** didn't reveal the appropriate on-off switch.

- What causes this behaviour?
- How can I prevent Launcher from launching upon drag(*-and-drop*)?

Comment: Launcher appearing maybe more suitable than launcher launching because nothing is actually launched?

Comment: technically agree (though the pun *is* intended... so long as it does not interfere (too much) with clarity :)

Comment: No objections to puns and alliteration but I just thought I'd point out that the launcher merely reveals itself but doesn't launch anything unless something is actually dropped on the relevant icon.